# Using Eclipse, what is the correct file structure to use program-ab for building bots?

Tags: java, eclipse, chatbot, aiml

I'm building a Java application with [program-ab](https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/wikis/ProgrammingInterface.wiki). Downloading and running the source code works fine, but it can't recognize the bot files when I add the jar into an Eclipse project.

My file structure is as follows:

```
| MY_APPLICATION
| src/main/java
| - com.company.bot.services
| - - botSvc.java
| bots
| - mybot
| - - aiml
| - - aimlif
| - - config
| - - data
| - - maps
| - - sets
```

Everything I say to it, it responds "I have no answer for that." and it is a "no match". What is the correct file structure?

Answer (score 0):

answer in case someone else is confused... The structure I have in the question is correct. On bot creation, the correct *name* has to be passed in, that matches the folder within the bots folder. A custom path can also be passed in.

For example:

```
Bot mybot = new Bot("mybot", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```